# Multi threading with Swing: Thread that updates & repaints?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I need to update and repaint my application every X milliseconds, and that means I need to create a thread that calls `frame.update()` which is a custom method, and `frame.repaint()` of `JFrame`, but my fear is if this will cause any deadlocks or other multithreading issues because as far as I remember `Swing` has its own thread to update components and such, so in this case I am a bit clueless and I am trying to research a bit before doing something that may bring me future issues.

What makes me think that it will cause problems is because I am using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` with a `new runnable`

Or is there an original way to do this with `SwingUtilities`?

Is it okay to create run a thread which will repaint the frame every X milliseconds?

Comment: Don't run a thread, use a timer: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html (`invokeLater` from a thread works fine though)

Comment: @zapl But isn't a timer the same as using a Thread? It does creates a new thread

Comment: not really, "Note that the Swing timer's task is performed in the event dispatch thread." - it schedules your code to run in the existing ui thread

Comment: How big of an X are we talking about here?

Comment: around 60ms i think

Comment: That doesn't sound too terrible, you should probably just use the Timer. JavaFX has more extensive animation support, if you're planning on doing a lot of this.

Answer (score 0):

with Swing Timer you do not have to take care from which thread you start calling a UI update.

[How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

```
timer = new Timer(speed, this); 
timer.setInitialDelay(pause); 
timer.start();
```